# Exporting from Wikimapia to KML?

Tags: kml, export, wikimapia

I'm not a API person but a GIS user and I would like to export points from a category from Wikimapia to KML.

Has anyone developed that?

It could be interesting to add the analysis that we need to the data from wikimapia.

Answer (score 6):

This link will give you the ge.kml file.  Open it with Google Earth and you can then export subset POI's to kml.

http://wikimapia.org/ge.kml

Answer (score 4):

The API can return KML, so you just need to do queries such as:

- Search queries (this one is probably the most relevant to what you need):

  http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=search&q=bus&key=YOUR_API_KEY&format=kml
- BBox queries:

  http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=box&bbox=37.617188,55.677586,37.70507,55.7271128&key=YOUR_API_KEY&format=kml
- A specific object:

  http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=object&id=10717928&key=YOUR_API_KEY&format=kml

Answer (score 3):

http://www.geodeg.com can export to KML files from Wikimapia

just enter name, category or location of POI, add them to poi list, and export

example :
insurance companies in usa
http://www.geodeg.com/search.php?q=insurance&language=&country=220

Answer (score -1):

http://www.motomapia.com/
here we can pan to an area in wikimapia. The feature which become visible are stored in motomapia database. Then we can download the POI directly. The poi is saved as CSV. We can open the .csv file in software's like manifold systems and convert to kml.

Answer (score -1):

I found a good tutorial from 2014 which helps build the wikimapia API query, using an excel file. It did not work smoothly for me, but I looked at what the excel is trying to do and you can fix it manually (for me - I had to manually enter the coordinates in the bbox). If you choose KML format, just add .kml to the file name after it's downloaded, and you can open it in google earth / qgis / arcGIS.

http://blog.cartong.org/2014/10/30/tutorial-using-wikimapia-data-in-qgis/