# How do I export neighbourhoods in wikimapia to KML file

Tags: kml, export, google, maps, wikimapia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I export from Wikimapia to KML](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22172/how-do-i-export-from-wikimapia-to-kml)

I am trying to export the neighbourhoods in Wikimapia to KML format. Is this possible? These are all the predefined neighbourhoods that's gets highlighted on the mouse over.

Answer (score 1):

Wikimapia has an API which you can use to export to KML.

You can export using:

- Search queries :

> http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=search&q=bus&key=YOUR_API_KEY&format=kml

- BBox queries:

> http://api.wikimapia.org/?function=box&bbox=37.617188,55.677586,37.70507,55.7271128&key=YOUR_API_KEY&format=kml