# Using updated wikimapia API to export data

Tags: export, api, json, wikimapia

My goal is to get a json export from Wikimapia. I'm trying to use their [updated API](http://wikimapia.org/api/?action=how_to) but I always get no objects returned no matter what coordintes or categories I specify.

Here is my example query (?key=example is a valid key, but I also tried my own API key with the same result):

```
http://api.wikimapia.org/?key=example&function=place.getbyarea&coordsby=bbox&bbox=46.7674%2C56.1952%2C48.5939%2C56.8782&category=17&count=100&format=json
```

P.S. [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22172/exporting-from-wikimapia-to-kml/22181#22181) is no longer valid as it uses [deprecated methods](http://wikimapia.org/api/#oldbox)

Comment: I have the same problem, anyone can help us ? How can we download data from wikimapia. Looks like their API doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the tool I developed : https://github.com/martinedoesgis/wikimapia-export

I use **function=box** and it is still working, but it looks like **function=place.getbyarea** isn't.